Trying to access array offset on value of type null in mvc
I get this error message when I run the program

Trying to access array offset on value of type null

This is what's on the line that gives the error:
if (file_exists('../app/controllers/' . $url[0] . '.php')) {
            $this->controller = $url[0];
            unset($url[0]);
        }

I'm learning phpmvc and I access the public folder,
The output should be "home/index" which corresponds to the Home file in the controller folder
The following are the contents of Home.php in the controller folder :
<?php

class Home
{
    public function index()
    {
        echo "home/index";
    }
}


Presumably $url is null then. Where/when does that variable get defined? In what file / context is the code running which causes the error? How is the second snippet related to that? Provide a [mre] of the issue, if you would please. See also [ask] and the [tour]. You can [edit] your post. Thanks.

 if($url[0]!='' || $url[0]!=null){
      if (file_exists('../app/controllers/' . $url[0] . '.php')) {
                $this->controller = $url[0];
                unset($url[0]);
            }
    }


first add condition to verify $url[0] value is empty or null
-if value is nt empty or null ur code will execute
-u can add else condition if value is empty or null

